# Astray cytoscape indentifying floating values as integer

Tags: cytoscape

When I import node data from .xlsx file, I found some floating variables would be considered as integer ones, which finally leads to an uncorrect input (for example, 0.3-->0). After some search on-line, I found some information about it in official document:

"The first field is always the column name: it cannot contain spaces. If present, the class field defines the name of the class of the data values. For example, java.lang.String or String for Strings, java.lang.Double or Double for floating point values, java.lang.Integer or Integer for integer values, etc. If the value is actually a list of values, the class should be the type of the objects in the list. If no class is specified in the header line, Cytoscape will attempt to guess the type from the first value. If the first value contains numbers in a floating point format, Cytoscape will assume java.lang.Double; if the first value contains only numbers with no decimal point, Cytoscape will assume java.lang.Integer; otherwise Cytoscape will assume java.lang.String. Note that the first value can lead Cytoscape astray"

from http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Node_and_Edge_Column_Data.html

However, it didn't point out how to solve this tricky bug if user import data via .xlsx format. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  When you are doing the import, you can click on the column header of the column that was miss-characterized.  That will bring up a dialog where you can change the column from Floating Point to Integer.